# Maven 2 and Themes in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven

I have a problem with Maven and themes. I was making examples from this tutorial:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-themes-tutorial-example/
And in themes tutorial I have a problem. In this example author is using "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse. I'm using maven 2 and structure of my folders is different.
And I don't know where I should make a "themes" catalogue. I tried to make it in "main/resources", "webapp/resources/themes", "webapp/themes" but it's not working. 
Of course I have `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` in my servlet-config file. And also I added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css"/>` in my JSP file like people said in comments under this tutorial. But styles still don't change. So, anyone know what should I do to properly configure themes in Maven?

Answer (score 1):

The `WebContent` folder from the tutorial will be `src\main\webapp` in maven.

So for example  `WebContent\index.jsp` will be mapped to `src\main\webapp\index.jsp`

Then you do not need to modify any paths or resource mappings, because the generated war-files (Eclipse Dynamic Web Project with `WebContent` folder  and maven project with `src\main\webapp`) will be equals.

Comment: Ok, so in this way I should make a "webapp/themes" folder. But when I do this and put my css files into this catalogue it still doesn't work. When I try to change my style i get a warn: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloMVC/themes/default.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'.                                                        All files are the same as in tutorial.

Comment: I have had a look at the tutorial, one important point is that you put the files from the tutrial `resources` folder into mavens `src\main\resources` folder.

Comment: @Karol Skupień: BTW you can also create and studi a simple Spring Roo Web Application, it has by default two different themes and uses maven.

Comment: Yes, I put my properties files into this folder. Here you have my catalogue structure: http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/3583/springmvc.png / And about your second comment: Are you saying about this? http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html